# How to find an orthogonal vector given two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I´m trying to find a vector $\vec{c} = $ , which is orthogonal to vector $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$:

As far I understood, I have to show that:

$$\langle a,c\rangle=0 $$ 
$$\langle b,c\rangle=0 $$

So if I would like to determine an orthogonal vector regarding:  \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}
I just intuitively uses: $$\langle v,w\rangle=1 \cdot(-1)+1\cdot 1=0 $$ in order to arrive at \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
My problem is that I just dont know a mechanic way to solve for an orthogonal vector. It was more a educated guess.

For example, given: 
$\vec{a} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ how do I find a orthogonal vector?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about a cross product?

Comment: Recall $a.(a \times c) = c.(a \times c) = 0$

Comment: Ok. So taking the cross product gives me orthogonal vector in  $\mathbb{R}^3$. And how to approach the same question in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example...I mean with two vectors each having two componetns?

Comment: I don't see how you can have an orthogonal to 2 vectors in  $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Hmm, I dont know, maybe you have two dependent vector or so, which is not apparent on the first sight. Then you have to prove it whether there exist a orthogal vector or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $m$ orthogonal vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m$ in $\mathbb R^n$, a vector orthogonal to them is any vector $x$ that solves the matrix equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}v_1^T \\ v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_m^T\end{pmatrix} x = 0.$$

To put this a bit more concretely, suppose

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}v_{11} \\ v_{12} \\ \vdots \\ v_{1n}\end{pmatrix},\quad
v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}v_{21} \\ v_{22} \\ \vdots \\ v_{2n}\end{pmatrix},\ 
\ldots,\quad 
v_m = \begin{pmatrix}v_{m1} \\ v_{m2} \\ \vdots \\ v_{mn}\end{pmatrix},\  
\mbox{and}\quad 
x = \begin{pmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

where the numbers $v_{ij} \in \mathbb R$ are all known 
and the numbers $x_i \in \mathbb R$ are all unknown.
Then the matrix equation above can also be written

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{12} & \cdots & v_{1n} \\
v_{21} & v_{22} & \cdots & v_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
v_{m1} & v_{m2} & \cdots & v_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

This is equivalent to the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccl}
v_{11}x_1 &+& v_{12}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& v_{1n}x_n  &=& 0, \\
v_{21}x_1 &+& v_{22}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& v_{2n}x_n  &=& 0, \\
\vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots \\
v_{m1}x_1 &+& v_{m2}x_2 &+& \cdots &+& v_{mn}x_n  &=& 0.
\end{array}$$

That is, you need to solve a linear system of $m$ equations with $n$ unknowns.
This is something you can do using row reduction.

The solution will never be unique; if the vector $x$ is a solution
then the vector $cx$ is also a solution, where $c$ is any scalar constant.
If the $m$ vectors include fewer than $n-1$ independent vectors, the solution is not even unique up to a scalar constant;
you can have multiple vectors in different directions that are all orthogonal
to the given vectors.
If $m \geq n$ there may not be a solution at all;
the $m$ vectors may span $\mathbb R^n$.
There will, however, be solutions as long as the set of given vectors does not contain
$n$ or more mutually independent vectors.

In your particular case, if you are not aware of the fact that the cross-product
of two independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is orthogonal to each of those vectors,
you have

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}v_{11}\\v_{12}\\v_{13}\end{pmatrix} 
      = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} \quad \mbox{and} \quad
  v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}v_{21}\\v_{22}\\v_{23}\end{pmatrix} 
      = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix},$$

so you could solve the system of equations

$$\begin{eqnarray}
-1\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 + 1 \cdot x_3 &=& 0, \\
\sqrt{2}\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 - 1 \cdot x_3 &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Blindly applying the methods I was taught in high school, I find this is equivalent to

$$\begin{array}{ccccccl}
 x_1 &-& x_2 &-& x_3 &=& 0, \\
&&\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)x_2 &+&\left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right) x_3 &=& 0.
\end{array}$$

At this point we can make an arbitrary choice of for $x_3$ and proceed to solve the
equations as a system of two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: that is great. thank you for taking so much time

Comment: I looked around for an answer like this, didn't find one, so I figured _someone_ ought to write it up.

Comment: If memory serves, my LinAlg professor in college would have us pick $x_3 = 0$ just to make things easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary vector  $$c=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$ then write down the equations in terms of $xyz$:

$$\langle a,c\rangle = 0;\langle b,c\rangle = 0$$

The solutions to this system will all lie on one line and this gives you the perpendicular vector.

**Easy example:** Let $$a= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}; b= \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then set $\langle a,c\rangle=x = 0$ and $\langle b,c\rangle=y = 0$. So we conclude that $$c=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\z\end{bmatrix}$$ is perpendicular for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: May I ask you for a numeric example if possible?

Comment: @Mamba done - let me know if unclear I rushed a little.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a "quick" $(O(d^2))$ algorithm to generate $d-1$ mutually orthogonal vectors that are perpendicular to $\vec{x}$ where $d$ is the size of $\vec{x}$, while working on a semi-related problem (I needed to generate $d-2$ mutually orthogonal vectors that are perpendicular to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, (where $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are perpendicular.. unfortunately the concept of vector cross product does not exist when d is not 3).
The alternative would be to apply Gram-Schmidt which would take $O(d^3)$

I made use of something called a Householder Transform ($H= I - 2nn^T$ (with $||n||=1$)) which conceptually works like a reflection on a d-dimensional hyperplane through the origin, with $n$ the vector normal to the hyperplane. The general idea is to reflect d orthogonal basis (an easy basis to use would be the usual basis (aka the d-size identity matrix $I_d$) , such one of the column vectors coincides with x.

Step 1: normalize x (take x and divide it by ||x||)

Step 2: let $n_1= \sqrt{\frac{1-x_1}{2}}$, and $n_j= \frac{-x_j}{\sqrt{2(1-x_1)}} $ with $j \in [2..d]$

Step 3: calculate $H = I - 2nn^T$.

Step 4: Columns 2 to d are orthogonal to $x$

Proof:
Since, the column vectors of $I_d$ are mutually orthogonal, it follows that the column vectors of the reflection of $I_d$ would also be mutually orthogonal. Hence all we need to do is to design $H$ such that we have the following property $HI = H = [x \text{  | }  V_{2..d} ] $, giving us $V_2, V_3 ... V_d$ mutually-orthogonal to $x$.

To construct $H$, we have
$x_i = I_{1,i} - 2n_in_1$
simplifying,

$x_1 = 1 - 2n_1^2$,

Solving for $n_1$, we get $n_1= \sqrt{\frac{1-x_1}{2}}$.

Similarly,
$x_j = -2n_1n_j$ for $j \in [2.. d]$,

Solving for $n_j$ we get $n_j= \frac{-x_j}{\sqrt{2(1-x_1)}}$

Finally, proof that $V_2 ... V_d$ are mutually orthogonal to $x$

$ V_{i,j} = I_{i,j} -2n_jn_i $

when $i=1$, $ V_{1,j} =  -2n_jn_1 = -2 \frac{-x_j}{2n_1}n_1  = x_j$

when $i=j$, $ V_{j,j} =  1-2n_jn_j = 1-2 \frac{x_j^2}{2(1-x_1)}  = \frac{1 -x_1 - x_j^2}{1-x_1}$

when $i \neq j, i \neq 1$, $ V_{i,j} =  -2n_in_j = -2 \frac{x_jx_i}{2(1-x_1)}  = \frac{-x_ix_j}{1-x_1}$

To show $V_j$ is orthorgonal to $x$,

$x^TV_j = \sum_{i=1}^d V_{i,j}x_i$

$= x_jx_1 + \dfrac{x_j -x_jx_1- x_j^3}{1-x_1}+\sum_{i\neq j, i\geq 2}^d \dfrac{-x_jx_i^2}{1-x_1}$

$=\dfrac{x_jx_1-x_jx_1^2}{1-x_1} + \dfrac{x_j -x_jx_1- x_j^3}{1-x_1}-\sum_{i\neq j, i\geq 2}^d \dfrac{x_jx_i^2}{1-x_1}  $

$= \dfrac{x_j}{1-x_1}(1-\sum_{i=1}^dx_i^2)=0$

Since $\|x\| = 1$ through step one, implying $\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2 = 1 $

(or we can just exploit the fact that by construction, $HH^T=H^TH=I$ implying the column vectors are mutually orthogonal to each other... )